# How to use protected enviroment variables from gitlab CI/CD inside serverless script?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, serverless

For security reasons i need to set up protected enviroment variables in gitlab CI/CD, the problem is that in the documentation only mentions how to use inside the .gitlab-ci.yml file,  but not in the index.js.

How i could get those enviroment variables to use inside of my index.js file:

i was thinking something like this:

```
exports.handler = function (somerArgsHere) { 

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.HOST,
    user: config.USER,
    password: config.PASSWORD,

  });
 //etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables should be available to your javascript process as process.env.NAME

Assuming that HOST, USER and PASSWORD are GitLab variables:

```
exports.handler = function (somerArgsHere) { 

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,

  });
```